# Scope and accessing outside variables in anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here, but I'm not sure what. I'm adding anonymous functions to an array for later execution, and creating them in a for loop with variables that change each iteration.

I'm expecting the logged values to be:
https:server.net/a
https:server.net/b

but instead I'm getting:
https:server.net/b
https:server.net/b

It looks like maybe when I redefine the function it overwrites the last version of it, but I'm not sure why. I would think that each anonymous function would be different.

Why? What am I doing wrong here?

Here's some sample code:

```
f = [];
items = ['a', 'b'];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var itemID = items[i];
    var itemAccessUrl = `https://server.net/${itemID}`;

    var func = function(){ 
        console.log(itemAccessUrl);
    };
    f.push(func);
}

console.log(f.length);
for(var j = 0; j < f.length; j++){
    func();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the nature of `var` scoping. `var` is not block scoped, it is "hoisted", as if you declared it at the top of your function.

You could declare itemAccessUrl using `let` instead of var, which is block scoped, but it depends on what browser support you require. *(Having said that, you're using templated strings, so you should be fine)*

Comment: If I change itemID and itemAccessUrl to let's instead of var's, the problem persists. If I change it for func, when I execute it later I get the error: "function is not defined". Is there some other way I need to call it?

Comment: That's from the line in your second for loop. Change that to `f[j]();`. Othewise, you would be calling the same function, just several times in a loop

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here? When you invoke your array's functions, they use the current value of `itemAccessUrl`, i.e. the last assigned string, with char 'b'. This because their invocation happens after the completion of first for-loop.

You can use a closure:

```
f = [];
items = ['a', 'b'];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var itemID = items[i];
    var itemAccessUrl = `https://server.net/${itemID}`;

    var func = (function(param) {
        return function () {
            console.log(param);
        };
    })(itemAccessUrl);
    f.push(func);
}

console.log(f.length);
for(var j = 0; j < f.length; j++){
    f[j]();
}
```

or bind your function to current param:

```
f = [];
items = ['a', 'b'];
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var itemID = items[i];
    var itemAccessUrl = `https://server.net/${itemID}`;

    var func = (function (param) {
        console.log(param);
    }).bind(null, itemAccessUrl);
    f.push(func);
}

console.log(f.length);
for(var j = 0; j < f.length; j++){
    f[j]();
}
```

Furthermore you have to change the second loop, invoking `f[j]();`